# Fancybox iframe type return value on close

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancxbox,it is possible to pass back a variable from fancybox child to parent.

In the child page there is text field called `banner_width1` (`<input name="banner_width"   id="banner_width1" type="text" size="5"  value="1000"/>`)

```
'onClosed':function() 
{
alert($("#banner_width1").val());
var x = $("#fancybox-frame").contentWindow.targetFunction();
alert(x.val());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using fancybox v1.3.4 then you won't be able to get the value (`.val()`) using the `onClosed` callback because `onClosed` will be executed when all the fancybox content has been already removed. You rather use `onCleanup` instead (you can still alert the value of `x` after closing fancybox though)

so for Fancybox **v1.3.4** use this API options

```
"onCleanup": function(){
 x = $('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('#banner_width1').val();
},
"onClosed": function(){
 alert("the value of input#banner_width1 is : "+x); // optional
}
```

make sure that you have declared `var x;` on top of your script to make it accessible from any callback or any other function.

for Fancybox **v2.x** use this API options

```
beforeShow : function(){
 x = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('#banner_width1').val();
},
afterClose: function(){
 alert("the value of input#banner_width1 is : "+x); // optional
}
```